# Retrieve lists from a list of lists based on the given first elements

Tags: python

```
list1 = [1, 3, 5, 7]
list2 = [[1, "name1", "sys1"], [2, "name2", "sys2"], [3, "name3", "sys3"], [4, "name4", "sys4"]]
```

I've got the following 2 lists, I would like to be able to retrieve from list2 every item that matched in list1.

so, the result would be like:

```
result = [[1, "name1", "sys1"], [3, "name3", "sys3"]]
```

Separately is there also an easy way to find out the items that did not match,

```
notmatch = [5, 7]
```

I have read this [Find intersection of two lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/python-intersection-of-two-lists) but it does not produce the result I need.

Comment: Related: [Select value from list of tuples where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876272/select-value-from-list-of-tuples-where-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> ids = set(list1)
>>> result = [x for x in list2 if x[0] in ids]
>>> result
[[1, 'name1', 'sys1'], [3, 'name3', 'sys3']]

>>> ids - set(x[0] for x in result)
{5, 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [3]: result=[i for i in list2 if i[0] in list1]
Out[4]: [[1, 'name1', 'sys1'], [3, 'name3', 'sys3']]

In [5]: nums=[elem[0] for elem in result]
In [6]: [i for i in list1 if i not in nums]
Out[6]: [5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use a `set` for looking up indices: it will have faster lookup time:

```
>>> indices = set(list1)
```

Matching items:

```
>>> matching = [x for x in list2 if x[0] in indices]
>>> matching
[[1, 'name1', 'sys1'], [3, 'name3', 'sys3']]
```

non-matching items:

```
>>> nonmatching = [x for x in list2 if x[0] not in indices]
>>> nonmatching
[[2, 'name2', 'sys2'], [4, 'name4', 'sys4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1, 3, 5, 7]
list2 = [[1, "name1", "sys1"], [2, "name2", "sys2"], [3, "name3", "sys3"], [4, "name4", "sys4"]]
result = []

for elem in list1:
    for x in range(len(list2)):
        if elem == list2[x][0]:
            result.append(list2[x])
print(result)
```