# Filter a list of tuples based on condition

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list like this:

```
A=[(1,'A'),(2,'H'),(3,'K'),(4,'J')]
```

Each member of this list is like this: (number, string)

Now if I want to select the members if the number is bigger than 2 and write the string, what should I do?

For example:
selecting the member with a number bigger than 2. the output should be: `'K','J'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select value from list of tuples where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876272/select-value-from-list-of-tuples-where-condition)

Answer (score 19):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[y for x,y in A if x>2]
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> A=[(1,'A'),(2,'H'),(3,'K'),(4,'J')]
>>> [y for x,y in A if x>2]
['K', 'J']
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

try :

```
In [4]: [x[1] for x in A if x[0] > 2]                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[4]: ['K', 'J']
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to filter based on some condition, then display a representation of those items. There are a few ways to do this.

List comprehension with filtering. This is usually considered idiomatic or “pythonic”

```
B = [char for char, val in A if val > 2]
```

Filter and map. This is lazy and useful if your list is very large and you don’t want to hold it all in memory at once.

```
greater_than_2 = filter(lambda a: a[1] > 2, A)
B = map(lambda a: a[0], greater_than_2)
```

Or a loop and accumulator. This is good if you have side effects you want to do for each element.

```
B = []
for char, val in A:
    if val > 2:
        B.append(char)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses map, filter and lambda functions to make it work. But it might be confusing for some. However, it is faster than list comprehension.

```
list(map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda x: x[0]>2, A)))
```

In short, first the filter function filters out the tuples in A where the first element is greater than 2. Then we take this filtered list and apply a mapping with another lambda function to select only the 2nd element (character).
The result is as desired:

```
['K', 'J']
```

Another tool to be aware of is the `compress` tool from `itertools`, which is also faster than list comprehension. But it returns tuples, so you need to use another map to get only character elements.

```
from itertools import compress
list(compress(A, map(lambda x: x[0]>2, A)))
Out: [(3, 'K'), (4, 'J')]
```