# Conditional selection of tuples from a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples as follows:

```
my_list = [(3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

I need to extract tuples in which number `1` is repeated less than 5 times. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876272/select-value-from-list-of-tuples-where-condition), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632188/explicitly-select-items-from-a-python-list-or-tuple) and some other posts, and based on these I have written the following:

```
results = []
for i in range(len(my_list)):           
    a = [elem for elem in my_list if my_list[i].count(1) < 5]
    results.append(a)
```

This is not working giving me another list of lists. Could anyone give me a hint what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: You need to iterate over the sublists in `my_list`: `my_list[i]`

Comment: Almost: `results = [elem for elem in my_list if elem.count(1) < 5]`, without a surrounding for-loop. It's just a one-liner, really.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. As usual with Python, things are simpler than we think:

```
 result = [t for t in my_list if t.count(1) < 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter solution can utilize a list comprehension with `sum`:

```
my_list = [(3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
result = [i for i in my_list if sum(c == 1 for c in i) < 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

using `filter` is a good option.

```
my_list = [(3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]


sol =list(filter (lambda x:x.count(1)<5, my_list))
print(sol)
```

output

```
[(3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
 (1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
 (2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
 (1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3),
 (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
 (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
 (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3),
 (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
 (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3),
 (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)]
```